# What are the advantages, for managing a single multisite instance of Drupal, to using drush make instead of git fetch & merge?

Tags: multi-sites, deployment, version-control, drush

I don't intend to publicly distribute an installation profile for my multisite instance. Are there still advantages to using platform/site makefiles to move code updates through dev/test/production environments compared to the alternative of pulling changes from either a platform repository (for cross-site changes) or a site repository (for site-specific changes)?

Comment: Using makefiles you have one place to overview what you have built together. But if your are the only one who needs to know it, and you do not use Aegir to manage the sites, then it's OK to use repositories directly.